# INPUT Field - Blue Focus Highlight ? Impossible to get rid of?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, focus

I have tried EVERYTHING to get rid of this focus blue highlight and absolutely nothing seems to work.

I have tried:

```
input:focus {
   outline: none; 
}
```

which I've read on here is the correct solution. It's not working though. Using the latest Chrome / Safari / Firefox the blue highlight is still there when clicking into focus.

It works in IE7 / IE8 funnily enough. I tried a javascript solution I read on stack as well where I add an *onclick:blur* method to the input, but this just made the input field uneditable?

Any solutions guys? Would prefer a clean CSS solution if possible.

Comment: Something else must be going on. IE7 and IE8 don't even have any focus glow to begin with - which is why it appears to work.

Comment: Check that you're not applying a border as well, that might be the case.

Comment: @andres-ilich I have border: 0px so no. :(

Comment: Here's a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YgQB4/) removing the outline on a textfield. Does it still show up blue when you focus it? If not, you probably have a CSS specificity issue as indicated in one of the answers below. Use Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools to see where the element gets its styles. You'll need to post some of your code for anyone to help you solve this because you've already identified the (seemingly) correct solution.

Comment: @skyline3000 Thanks Sky. You made me really sit back and look at it. Turns out it was a style being applied by a theme in a Drupal deployment. I wasn't seeing it in Chrome Dev Tools but Firebug showed it. Works now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That bit of css would only work if there's nothing more specific. Remember, css goes by the most specific rule taking precedence, so saying

```
input#myid:focus {  /* <--more specific, takes priority */
    outline: blue;
}

input:focus {  /* <--less specific, overridden by above */
    outline: none;
}
```

You can force the override with `!important`, though that can lead to other problems later on:

```
input:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Use Firebug to view the computed CSS for the element when it's hovered. It'll tell you where the rule(s) applied to element are coming from.

Comment: I don't think I can get more specific than this: '#block-search-form input.form-text:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 0px;
}'....and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and this worked for me

```
#search input[type="text"]:focus {
width: 180px;
outline: none;
}
```